# open ticket based on user credit in whmcs

Tags: whmcs, ticket-system

I want to give a default 50 credits to all users and when they open a ticket (subtract 5 credit) and if I do something for them I subtract some more credits from that user . and when the credit finishes they have to buy credit to have more support.
is there such addon for whmcs or any similar support script ? I don't want my customers abusing the support that I offer them and they usually tend to abuse it and expect I do anything for them for free just because I'm offering support .
is this possible with whmcs or any other script?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this can be done by standard WHMCS ways. The idea of WHMCS is selling products which have either recurring (monthly, quarterly, etc.) or one-time payments. The product you want to sale (support access) is not like above: it requeres a client to be charged on event (submit a ticket).